# has_many :through breaks upon find_or_initialize_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a model, Feed, that has and belongs to many FilteredUsers. In this case I have implemented it through a has_many :through relationship.

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :denials, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :filtered_users, :through => :denials
```

I would like to create a record if it doesn't exist or find the object if it does exist. When I try and use the find_or_initialize_by (or find_or_create_by) an exception is thrown saying `undefined method 'feed_id=' for <FilteredUser..`

Here is the code:

```
feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
user = feed.filtered_users.find_or_initialize_by_user_url(params[:user_url])
if params[:status] == "block"
  feed.filtered_users << user
else
  feed.filtered_users.delete(user)
end
feed.save
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or how to work around it DRYly?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like this `initialize_by` path doesn't make sense if the request is not `status=block` -- why bother initializing the record just to `delete` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, because it's a `has_many :through` relationship, the initialization has no way of knowing which `denial` the new `filtered_user` should be associated with.  If you want to use `find_or_initialize_by`, you need to run it on a specific `denial` that is associated with the `feed`.

Build a new filtered_user and associate it with a specific denial.

Second, agreeing with ErsatzRyan, the general logic seems a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to check the params[:status] first and then do what you need to do?

```
feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
if params[:status] == 'block'
   feed.filtered_users.build(:user_url => params[:user_url])
else
   feed.filtered_users.find_by_user_url(params[:user_url]).delete
end
feed.save
```

**warning this is air coded not tested**